# PHP textarea problem, $_POST returns empty array

Tags: php, html

I already read a lot of google results about my problem and any methods don't help me. `print_r($_POST)` returns me empty array, i try fix this for two days. I was try really a lot of methods, from stackoverlow, from other websites and any from this methods don't work for me. `$_POST` is empty array.

My code

```php
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

function updateRec($tbl, $index) {
    if($GLOBALS['connection'] !== null) {
        $connection = $GLOBALS['connection'];

        if($tbl == 'users') {

            //if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['rank'])) {
                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $login = test_input($_POST['username']);
                $pass = password_hash(test_input($_POST['password']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $rank = test_input($_POST['rank']);
                $q = "UPDATE $tbl SET id='$id', username='$login', password='$pass', rank='$rank' WHERE id='$index'";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(".$login.");</script>";
            //}
        }

        //mysqli_query($connection, $q);
        header('location: '.$tbl.'.php?page=1');
    }
}

function createForm($a) {   
    if ($a === 'edit') {
        echo "<center><div id='editForm'>";
        $q = "DESCRIBE ".$_GET['tbl']."";
        $qr = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connection'], $q);
        while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($qr)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> " . $rw['Field'] . "</td><br/>";
            echo "<td><textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='".$rw['Field']."' required></textarea></td>";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo '<form action="forms.php?action=saveE&tbl='.$_GET['tbl'].'&row='.$_GET['row'].'" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" style="transform: translate(5vw, -20vh); height: 0vh;">';
        echo '<button id="fButton" name="submit" style="">Zapisz</button></form>'. '<a href="'.$_GET['tbl'].'.php?page=1"><button id="fButton" style="transform: translate(5vw, 8vh); margin-left: 6%;">Anuluj</button></a>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</div></center>";
    };
    if ($a === 'saveE') {
        updateRec($_GET['tbl'], $_GET['row']);
    };
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device.width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p>Admin Control Panel</p>
    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

My textarea

```php
while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($qr)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> " . $rw['Field'] . "</td><br/>";
            echo "<td><textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='".$rw['Field']."' required></textarea></td>";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

I was too try use id instead name and it don't help me.

Comment: Your textareas are outside your form, so they won't be posted back

Comment: Oh... Very thank you!